# Adding a Like button for an existing FB Page

Tags: facebook

This seems like it should be simple enough, but I've gotten burned by messing up my FB like buttons in the past. So I just want to get some verification here before I dive in and lose any likes.

I have a webpage. I have a facebook page for that webpage already with a good amount of likes. I want to add a Like button to my Web page that upon clicking, likes my Facebook page.

Do I just put in my http://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpage in the "URL to Like" of the generator and that will like my FB Page?

I know it's simple - but just want a sanity check! I've lost a good amount of likes by improperly implementing this in the past. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what should do.

If you use the iframe version it's all you have to do.

If you use the XFBML version you should also initialize the javascript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Something like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: This kind of relates to another question I have. I would like to use XFBML, however I don't want to create an app. How do I initialize the FB.init({appID: 'your app id'...}); For my FB page (that's not an app). Thanks!